# How create FileStream but not save?

Tags: c#, filestream

I have code function

```
public static void DecryptFile(string inFile, string outFile, string password)
{
    // create and open the file streams
    using (FileStream fin = File.OpenRead(inFile),
              fout = File.OpenWrite(outFile))
    {
        int size = (int)fin.Length; // the size of the file for progress notification
        byte[] bytes = new byte[BUFFER_SIZE]; // byte buffer
        int read = -1; // the amount of bytes read from the stream
        int value = 0;
        int outValue = 0; // the amount of bytes written out

        // read off the IV and Salt
        byte[] IV = new byte[16];
        fin.Read(IV, 0, 16);
        byte[] salt = new byte[16];
        fin.Read(salt, 0, 16);

        // create the crypting stream
        SymmetricAlgorithm sma = CryptoHelp.CreateRijndael(password, salt);
        sma.IV = IV;

        value = 32; // the value for the progress
        long lSize = -1; // the size stored in the input stream

        // create the hashing object, so that we can verify the file
        HashAlgorithm hasher = SHA256.Create();

        // create the cryptostreams that will process the file
        using (CryptoStream cin = new CryptoStream(fin, sma.CreateDecryptor(), CryptoStreamMode.Read),
                  chash = new CryptoStream(Stream.Null, hasher, CryptoStreamMode.Write))
        {
            // read size from file
            BinaryReader br = new BinaryReader(cin);
            lSize = br.ReadInt64();
            ulong tag = br.ReadUInt64();

            if (FC_TAG != tag)
                throw new CryptoHelpException("File Corrupted!");

            //determine number of reads to process on the file
            long numReads = lSize / BUFFER_SIZE;

            // determine what is left of the file, after numReads
            long slack = (long)lSize % BUFFER_SIZE;

            // read the buffer_sized chunks
            for (int i = 0; i < numReads; ++i)
            {
                read = cin.Read(bytes, 0, bytes.Length);
                fout.Write(bytes, 0, read);
                chash.Write(bytes, 0, read);
                value += read;
                outValue += read;
            }

            // now read the slack
            if (slack > 0)
            {
                read = cin.Read(bytes, 0, (int)slack);
                fout.Write(bytes, 0, read);
                chash.Write(bytes, 0, read);
                value += read;
                outValue += read;
            }
            // flush and close the hashing stream
            chash.Flush();
            chash.Close();

            // flush and close the output file
            fout.Flush();
            fout.Close();

            // read the current hash value
            byte[] curHash = hasher.Hash;

            // get and compare the current and old hash values
            byte[] oldHash = new byte[hasher.HashSize / 8];
            read = cin.Read(oldHash, 0, oldHash.Length);
            if ((oldHash.Length != read) || (!CheckByteArrays(oldHash, curHash)))
                throw new CryptoHelpException("File Corrupted!");
        }

        // make sure the written and stored size are equal
        if (outValue != lSize)
            throw new CryptoHelpException("File Sizes don't match!");
    }
}
```

I need return FileStream (fout) and fout not save to hard disk

UPDATE:

YES, MemoryStream is good.  but then I will need to use the FileStream otherwise an error occurs:

not work:

```
using (ZipInputStream s = new ZipInputStream(fout))
{

  ZipEntry theEntry;
  while ((theEntry = s.GetNextEntry()) != null)//exception
```

is work:

```
using (ZipInputStream s = new ZipInputStream(File.OpenRead(zipFile)))
{

  ZipEntry theEntry;
  while ((theEntry = s.GetNextEntry()) != null)
```

I need to decrypt the file, unzip it and then still get the text without saving

Comment: Why would you create a `FileStream` if you don't want it saved to the disk?  `FileStream` is a stream view of a disk file.  Do you perhaps want some other type of stream?  Perhaps a `MemoryStream` is what you're looking for?

Comment: @ Jim Mischel, but...i edit post.

Comment: What exception do you get when not using a `FileStream`?

Comment: Access to the private stream is impossible.

Comment: if fout not Closed exception will be "EOF in header". ZipInputStream s - not initialize

Comment: Why not return the stream from the function, or even better, pass it in?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Don't use a second `FileStream`. You can use a [`MemoryStream`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.memorystream.aspx) instead.

```
using (FileStream fin = File.OpenRead(inFile))
  using(Stream fout = new MemoryStream())
...
```

Comment: @Brian - seeing as you need to access the stream from the calling function, why don't you simply _return_ it from the function, instead of using a `void` function?

Comment: @Oded: I don't understand what you are suggesting.  The caller already knows where the stream is since the caller passed in a `Stream` object, outstream.  Outstream might be a `FileStream` or a `MemoryStream` or whatever, but the *caller* created it.

Comment: @Brian - I can see the function taking 3 strings as inputs, creating some streams off them, but the caller doesn't _create_ your fout stream.

Comment: @Oded: In Denis's current code, the caller does not create the fout stream.  My proposal is that the caller **does** create the fout stream (which may or may not be a `FileStream`).  Hence my statement within my answer, "This leaves the responsibility of creating the `Stream` with the caller."

Answer (score 3):

I recommend changing your method signature to:

```
public static void DecryptFile(string inFile, string password, Stream outStream)
```

or

```
public static void DecryptFile(string inFile, string password, string outFile)
```

(The 2nd can be implemented very easily by just calling the first with a `FileStream` parameter).

This leaves the responsibility of creating the `Stream` with the caller, which has the advantage over Oded's solution that it does not necessarily store the entire output in memory; the user can choose to provide a `Stream` that consumes the output as it is provided.  This may be important if the file being decrypted is especially large.

Comment: Thanks. I understood it. I changed message